# how to implement instant comments and replies using graphql apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, state-management

I am creating a messaging board feature within my application using GraphQL and Apollo State Management.

My problem is that I want to update the cache directly but due to pagination / infinite scrolling I am running into issues

```
 update: (cache, { data }) => {
      const commentQuery: any = cache.readQuery({
        query: QUERY,
        variables: {
          page: 1,
          limit: 8,
          shortlistId: Number(id),
        },
      });
      const currentComment = commentQuery?.getCommentQuery?.comments?.find((item) => item?._id === data?.createComments?.reply_to);
      cache.writeQuery({
        query: QUERY,
        variables: {
          page: 1,
          limit: 8,
          shortlistId: Number(id),
        },
        data: {
          getCommentQuery: {
            ...commentQuery?.getCommentQuery,
            comments: [
              ...commentQuery?.getCommentQuery?.comments,
              {
                ...currentComment,
                ...currentComment?.replies,
                comments: [...currentComment?.replies?.comments, ...(Array.isArray(data?.createComments) ? data?.createComments : [])],
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      });
```

because apollo wants the variables to be the same as stored in cache my read / write to cache update function works perfectly when I am on the page:1 as thats whats stored in cache

my problem is when i am on page: 5 and try this i will get an error as my readQuery returns null due to the data being different from cache

I also tried this approach

```
 const cacheId = cache.identify(data?.createComments);

      cache.modify({
        fields: {
          commentQuery: (prev, { toReference }) => {
            return [prev, toReference(cacheId ?? "")];
          },
        },
      });
```

but i am running into similar issues